# Hibernate SQLQuery with condition in list

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to pass a list of integers to SQLQuery. However it throws an error saying `"Exception : could not locate named parameter [ids]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [ids]"`

This is what my query looks like :

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
//Fill something in ids
return session.createSQLQuery("select igf.foo_id from group_feed igf where igf.id in (:ids)")
    .setMaxResults(pageSize)
    .setParameterList("ids", ids)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(GroupFeed.class))
    .list();
```

What am i doing wrong? Am I not allowed to use `setParameterList` with `Hibernate SQLQuery` ? I was not able to make out much from the documentation of Hibernate in jBoss.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
```

Generates an empty list with a 5 slot capacity:

```
ids {null, null, null, null, null}

for (Integer i : ids) {
            System.out.println("" + i);
}
```

Would not print anything. The list is empty.

Are you sure the list is filled with at least one item?

The way `Hibernate` looks up parameters I think you must:

```
return session.createSQLQuery("select igf.foo_id from group_feed igf where igf.id in ( :ids )")
.setMaxResults(pageSize)
.setParameterList("ids", ids)
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(GroupFeed.class))
.list();
```

I think `Hibernate` is not aware of the `:ids` since it is `(:ids)`.

Comment: Still the same. The exception says : "Exception : could not locate named parameter [ids];" . I guess this refers to the fact that 'ids' data is not found.

Comment: I didn't want to put the initialization code here, hence I put this comment -> //Fill something in ids. I guess what @Vikram says is correct.

Comment: I understand that you do not want to :)